# Passing Objects to Component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I'm fairly new to the react side of life and have come across a slightly annoying issue with my Syntax that I could do with a little help on.

The premise is very simple:

I am trying to pass an object as a prop to a Component.

Parent Element: -- Trying to pass the state to the Totals component

```
class Dash_overview extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            companies: {
                title: 'companies on record',
                value: null,
                messurement: 'Companies'
            },
            earning: {
                title: 'total earning',
                value: null,
                messurement: 'mill'
            }
        }
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="overview-container">
                <div className="totals">
                    <Totals values={this.state.companies}/>
                    <Totals values={this.state.earning}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Child Component -- which is going to use the values passed to it

```
class Totals extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            
        }
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="totals_comp">
                <h3>{companies.title}</h3>
                <h3>{companies.value}</h3>
                <h3>{companies.messurement}</h3>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

--

Im probably making a silly mistake but I have tried a few different variations of this without success so would really value someone pointing out where I am going wrong. :)

Thanks in advance,
Wally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Try this.*

```
const { title,value,messurement }  = this.props.values;
    
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="totals_comp">
                <h3>{title}</h3>
                <h3>{value}</h3>
                <h3>{messurement}</h3>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: this worked as intended - thank you for your help - quick question on this answer / why is react unable to take props passed into its components i.e. is this expected to have to define in the component the props you are passing // In Vue.js you have to define an array of props i.e. props=['title', 'value', measurement] - if you have any documentation on this that would be great - for the moment - thanks again for the help :)

Comment: @Wally React components are passed a single argument, `props`, which is an object. You don't *need* to define the properties ([propTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)) of this object, but you need to know/understand what properties are being passed in order to access them. You stuffed all the state into a property called `values`, so you needed to unstuff them from `values`. [Components and props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) may help.

Comment: In react .props perform as a  data communication from parent to child component. When props value change , the component receive that prop rerender agan . Complete guide for your curiosity read documentation here https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 1):

You can spread the state values into the child component props, the object keys will be the prop names used within the component.

```
<Totals {...this.state.companies}/>
<Totals {...this.state.earning}/>
```

Or explicitly pass the prop values

```
const { messurement, title, value } = this.state.companies;

...

<Totals
  messurement={messurement}
  title={title}
  value={value}
/>
<Totals
  messurement={messurement}
  title={title}
  value={value}
/>
```

And then in the child access via props

```
<div className="totals_comp">
  <h3>{this.props.title}</h3>
  <h3>{this.props.value}</h3>
  <h3>{this.props.messurement}</h3>
</div>
```

## Issue

`values={this.state.companies}` takes the state object value and assigns it to a prop named `values`, but then in the child component you don't reference it at all. i.e. like `props.values.title`.

Comment: no don't, pass them as a named parameter and grab them as expected instead

Comment: @Qchmqs When spread the object keys are used to provide the prop name, which matches what is being accessed in the component.

Comment: which isn't very predictable with two objects prone to change at any moment, and doesn't even address the real question, which is how to access the props

Comment: @Qchmqs Please read the included reason for issue and *entire* suggested solution, which covers reading/accessing the passed props.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are passing {title: 'companies on record',value: null,messurement: 'Companies'} as values prop, you should consume values from the other component. if you want to use companies name do this :

```
<div className="overview-container">
        <div className="totals">
            <Totals companies={this.state.companies}/>
            <Totals companies={this.state.earning}/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and then do this on Totals component:

```
const {companies}=this.props
render(){
  return (
    <div className="totals_comp">
        <h3>{companies.title}</h3>
        <h3>{companies.value}</h3>
        <h3>{companies.messurement}</h3>
    </div>
 )}
```